# Using a lambda with std::advance along with std::for_each()

Tags: c++11, lambda, foreach

I need to use std::for_each() to iterate through a list. However, in the UnaryFunction part of for_each(), I need to use a lambda which actually advances the iterator by means of std::advance().

For instance

```
for_each(beginIter, endIter, lambda);
```

and

```
auto lambda [] = (<Iter parameter>){advance(Iter parameter, 1)};
```

I am expecting that when the lambda returns, the for_each() would resume iterating from the position where the lambda left off.

Is this understanding correct?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: Would like to add that the lambda parameter is by reference.

Comment: `std::for_each` gives you references, not iterators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way.

The `UnaryFunction` that is `std::for_each` parameter takes the result of dereferencing the iterator as its argument, not the iterator itself. Therefore you cannot modify the iterator inside the lambda.

With the usage you shown, you should get compiler error that the lambda parameter type doesn't match expectations of the `for_each` template, such as

`no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector<int>::iterator&’`

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ZCd1Gu)